# Make badges more descriptive

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-interface, information-display

Perhaps it's just me, but I don't always find the badge descriptions that clear. For instance, what badges can be awarded multiple times and what badges are just awarded once? The suffrage badge for example implies to me that it's awarded multiple times, but seems to just be awarded once (at least I've only ever got it once and I've used all 30 votes multiple times!)

If it's not always feasible to get the whole description in one phrase, perhaps badges could have a longer, more detailed description when you click on the badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) is a simple listing.  You can find a community-maintained, detailed list in this post:

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: Thanks for that link, it's very helpful though a bit out the way? Perhaps it could be linked to more prominently or the badge descriptions themselves made longer on the actual badge page?

Comment: Gotta upvote a link to my question....

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, what badges can be awarded multiple times and what badges are just awarded once?

If a badge can be awarded more than once, it will say so in the description. For example:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question
>
> Asked a question with 10,000 views. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

if it does *not* say that, the badge *cannot* be awarded multiple times.